# ListView Item ID homescreen widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I have homescreen `widget` with `ListView`

How can I obtain number of current `Item` which was clicked:
I've tried to do it by following way:
Insite custom class which extends 
`AppWidgetProvider`

```
 public void onUpdate(Context ctxt, AppWidgetManager mgr,
                         int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int i=0; i<appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
            Intent svcIntent=new Intent(ctxt, WidgetService.class);

            svcIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
            svcIntent.setData(Uri.parse(svcIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

            RemoteViews widget=new RemoteViews(ctxt.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget);

            widget.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetIds[i], R.id.contacts,
                    svcIntent);

            Intent clickIntent=new Intent(ctxt, AppWidget.class);


            clickIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_REFRESH);
            clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds[i]);

            PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxt, 0 , clickIntent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            widget.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.contacts, pi);
            mgr.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], widget);
        }
        super.onUpdate(ctxt, mgr, appWidgetIds);
    } 

@Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("gotcha","receive");


        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_REFRESH)) {

            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            int extrass= -1;
            if(extras!=null) {
                 extrass = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);
            }

            Log.i("receive", Integer.toString(extrass) ) ; // Here is I've expected to see Item ID

        }
```

But It's not helped. I've just see different numbers (not Items ID)

How can I obtain them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is

```
  PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxt, 0 , clickIntent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Because if you always give 0 as `requestCode`, and the flag is `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, all the list items refer to the same `PendingIntent` which is update by the lasted.

So just give different requestCode to the PendingIntent will solve this problem, please use

```
PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxt,  appWidgetIds[i] , clickIntent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)`
```

instead.
    And also set the OnClickFillIntent to the RemoteView in the `adapter.getViewAt()`

```
    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(pkg, R.layout.item);
    Intent i = new Intent().putExtra("position", position);
    rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.item, i);
```

Then you can retrieve the appwidget id , as well as the list item position.

Comment: It's not helped I still get same Id as after first clikc

Comment: you want get the appWidgetId or the list item id?

Comment: @Pepelac  if you want to get list item id, use:  RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(pkg, R.layout.item);
    Intent i = new Intent().putExtra("position", position);
    rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.item, i);

Answer (score 0):

Read it once I think you get what should we do

When using collections (eg. ListView, StackView etc.) in widgets, it is very costly to set PendingIntents on the individual items, and is hence not permitted. Instead this method should be used to set a single PendingIntent template on the collection, and individual items can differentiate their on-click behavior using setOnClickFillInIntent(int, Intent).